# SearchViewCompat in support package vs. SearchDialog

Tags: android, compatibility, searchview

`android.support.v4.widget.SearchViewCompat` is supposed to capture search queries, but the official tutorial recommends using `SearchDialog`:

http://developer.android.com/training/search/backward-compat.html

Which approach is better? Should I use `SearchViewCompat` with a separate activity like this:

http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html#create-sa

Comment: searchviewcompat is WORTHLESS all it does is add the searchview if you are api 11 or above and leaves your ui broken for devices people actually have.

Comment: The solution is to use ActionbarSherlock which contains a SearchView that works in all devices.